# Qt Creator and Valgrind memory analyzer

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator, valgrind

How do I run the Valgrind memory analyzer in Qt Creator if the program asks for user input? No terminal window pops up, unlike when I just run the application itself. I have **Run in Terminal** checked.

Everything is displayed under the tab *Application Output*. And Valgrind memory analyzer just waits.

[This](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/42157) is a similar problem. But no solution.